# NetworkX Graph attributes in a single table

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, tabulate

I am trying to create a table displaying the attributes of nodes in a NetworkX (using Python) graph. The functions used to get these attributes generate a list of the nodes with their assigned attribute and are generated like in the following:

```
import networkx as nx

# degrees of nodes
pprint(g.degree())

# clustering coefficient
pprint(nx.clustering(g))
```

I should like to be able to compile these into a table with intuitive overview in the following format:

```
node    degree    clustering coefficient
----------------------------------------
a       2         3
b       1         1
...
```

Any tips on how to do so? Perhaps using a dict and tabulate but I am not quite sure... Would be grateful for any tips!

**Edit**
I found a way to do some simple printing, but it isn't formatted very nicely and doesn't make for nice syntax:

```
for n in g.nodes():
    print(n, g.degree(n), nx.clustering(g, n))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a Pandas dataframe (`pd.DataFrame`) to store this data, which I would construct in a list comprehension of dictionaries (each dictionary corresponding to a row in the final data frame). Here's how I would do that with two attributes, `in_degree` and `out_degree` for each node:

```py
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
g = nx.DiGraph()

# ... populate the Digraph ...

def compute_indegree(node, digraph):
  return digraph.in_degree(node)

def compute_outdegree(node, digraph):
  return digraph.out_degree(node)

attr_dicts = [
  { 'node': node,
    'in_degree': compute_indegree(node, g), \
    'out_degree': compute_outdegree(node, g)} \
  for node in g.nodes
]

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(attr_dicts)
dataframe.set_index('node', inplace=True)
print(dataframe)
```

The final print line neatly formats the resulting DataFrame:

[image: Printline results]

If you modify or add the above functions `compute_indegree` and `compute_outdegree` to return other stats like your clustering coefficient, the table will still populate as above.

Comment: thanks! i found a way to list everything, but this makes for nicer syntax!